# How to handle dynamic routes in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, api, url

I'm creating an API via PHP. I need to let users see a particular user. For example if someone goes to `mysite.com/users/2`, he must get the data about the user with id=2.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ^([-/_a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)$  index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The variable $url in `index.php` contains the whole url (for example `users/2`)

I use something like `if($url == "users"){ //code }` for routes, but what can I do with `id` that can be various?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have examples? Have you tried looking up different solutions? Have you thought of using a php framework?

Comment: I thought maybe I should use `explode` function, but I didn't find a solution how to use it.

Comment: `explode` could possibly work. What does `$url` contain when you go to `mysite.com/users/2`?

Comment: it contains the whole url (for example 'users/2')

Comment: So you could [`explode('/', $url)`](http://php.net/explode) and then use each part or segment to route to different places :)

Comment: but I can only use something like `if($url[0] == 'users' && $url[1] == 1)`... But I need to make it dynamic... Can I use `if($url[0] == 'users' && is_int($url[1]) && !isset($url[2]))` ? Looks scary...

Comment: It is scary. You should consider using [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or some other PHP framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have everything in `$url`, you can just use `explode()`

Here's an example:

```
$url = "users/1234";
$url_array = explode("/", $url, 2);
echo $url_array[1];
```

This doesn't handle any errors, and as you stated in the comments, you'd need to implement those. So, unless this is a very small project it does seem safer, more maintanable, faster, etc. to use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), or perhaps a micro-framework [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) or [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) if you only need a few features.

Comment: I thought about this way of solving the problem, but I hoped there is another variant to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to include the url in the RewriteRule:

```
# Redirect all requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then in your index.php:

```
$urlparts = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));
if($urlparts[0] == 'users'){
    //find user with id $urlparts[1]
}
```